# Wrap text around other boxed text

Tags: formatting

I'm attempting to make a document that has boxes of text with notes that the other text wraps around. I've tried doing this both using in the document and using \newenvironment. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
%Environment for Block Notes. Does NOT work how I want:
\newenvironment{NoteBox}{
 \begin{wraptable}{o}{0.4\linewidth}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
}{
 \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
%This is my notebox that works generally how I want it but is incredibly tedious
\begin{wraptable}{o}{0.4\linewidth}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  When once our labour has\\begun, the comfort that\\enables us to endure it is\\the
  prospect of its end...\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[2]
%For some reason, the Notebox environment doesn't seem to work
\begin{NoteBox}
 When once our labour has\\begun, the comfort that\\enables us to endure it is\\the
 prospect of its end...
\end{NoteBox}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This produces the following pdf:

[image]

This code seems to have a few problems: the gap above and below the first box is very large and all the line breaks have to be inserted manually. Additionally, typing all those commands every time is really tedious. When using the Notebox environment to create the second box, it seems to work even less well, like without the text wrapping.

I'm looking for something that does what the \wraptable is doing, but with automatic line-breaking and smaller vertical gaps that can used to create a new environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm+.6666em+.8pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,text width=5cm,minimum width=5cm}]
\node {\lipsum[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm just wondering why you used such a strange size for the wrapfigure (5cm+.6666em+.8pt)?

Comment: @Crigl 5cm is the text width, 0.3333em is the default value of `inner sep`, i.e. the distance between the text and the border (counted twice), and `0.4pt` is the width of the border (also counted twice). Therefore we get `5cm+.6666em+.8pt`. You may notice that I loaded `calc` to perform the calculation.